# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can only write data to relations with a single path

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, insert, overwrite

when insert overwrite a partitioned table,the error occur

```
create table example(id string, name string, day_time string)
insert overwrite table example partition(day_time) select * from .....
```

try to set the following config

```
spark_conn.sql("SET spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true")
    spark_conn.sql("SET spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
```

but the error occur again